# Increasing number of ports in circuitikz gate

Tags: circuitikz

Is it possible to add two ports to the gates (nand, and, or, not) in circuitikz on the top and bottom for reference voltages in a similar fashion to how they exist for the op amp?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the same mechanism given for op-amps in the manual by defining your own ports

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
 (opamp.+) node[ left ] {$v_+$}
 (opamp.-) node[left] {$v_-$}
 (opamp.out) node[right] {$v_o$}
 (opamp.down) node[ground] {}
 (opamp.up) ++ (0,.5) node[above] {\SI{12}{\volt}}
 -- (opamp.up)
;
\draw (4,0) node[european and port] (euand) {} 
(euand.south) node[ground] {}
(euand.north) ++(0,0.5) node[above] {\SI{12}{\volt}}
-- (euand.north);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]